# How to have methods in common for several (partial) views

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in my asp.net core web project i have two partial views that are displaying products. the first one shows them in a big layout, while the second one displays them in a smaller, regular layout.

both partial views need a method that composes a SEO-friendly url (using the product name and further information which are provided from the ViewModel). this method should somehow be accessible to the both views.

where can i place it inside of the asp.net core application? are there any particular conventions that must be followed?

Comment: make a class with the needed methods and inject it into both partial views

Comment: @JoeAudette thank you, it worked. do you want to add an answer, so that i can mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
```

Uses a view in current folder with this name. If none is found, searches the Shared folder

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName.cshtml")
```

A view with this name must be in the same folder

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder/ViewName.cshtml")
@Html.Partial("/Views/Folder/ViewName.cshtml")
```

Locate the view based on the application root. Paths that start with "/" or "~/" refer to the application root

```
@Html.Partial("../Account/LoginPartial.cshtml")
```

Locate the view using relative paths